# Is the directory image a relevant concern for SEO?

Tags: seo, images

Drupal stores images in:

```
/sites/default/files/whatever.png
```

Would it be better if I instead could find a way to have:

```
/images/whatever.png
```

OR even:

```
/whatever.png
```

Is there any way to know for sure this is or is not a factor?

Answer (score 3):

It is absolutely okay that Drupal stores images in such a directory. While the filename should be descriptive, the `alt` attribute is more important for SEO. The name of the directory images are stored in is of very low importance.

You can read about Google's image publishing guidelines [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/114016?hl=en).

Comment: Even though the directory name is of low importance, surely the name of the file is?

Comment: @coderama Yes. Quoting from Google's own guidelines: “The filename can give Google clues about the subject matter of the image. Try to make your filename a good description of the subject matter of the image. […] Descriptive filenames can also be useful to users: If we're unable to find suitable text in the page on which we found the image, we'll use the filename as the image's snippet in our search results.”